# Excel VBA - How to get cell value at repeating fixed interval from a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel worksheet with the following format:

```
    Club A  Total:    ##        Club B  Total:    ##         Club C   Total:    ##
            Account Placement           Account Placement             Account Placement
            Value:    ##                Value:    ##                  Value:    ##

                                        Account Placement
                                        Value:    ##

    Club D  Total:    ##        Club E  Total:    ##         Club F  Total:     ##
            Account Placement           Account Placement            Account Placement
            Value:    ##                Value:    ##                 Value:    ##      

            Account Placement 
            Value:    ##

            Account Placement 
            Value:    ##
```

For any club, they may have more than one account placement added later on, aligned to respective column as above. My objective is to calculate the Total for each club, which will automatically account for all Account Placement under a club, with the calculation goes as:

Eg. Total of Club B = Value of Account Placement 1 + Value of Account Placement 2 + ...

Same goes with other clubs. I have managed to locate each club and the value of first account using the following code:

```
Dim ra As Range 
For Each ra In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If InStr(1, ra.Text, "Account Placement") > 0 Then
        accvalue = Cells(ra.Row + 1, ra.Column + 1).Value
    End If
Next ra
```

The above code finds "Account Placement" horizontally, ie. it will get 1st value of Club A, then 1st value of Club B, then 1st value of Club C, then 2nd value of Club B, then 1st value of Club D etc. with respect to the above illustrated worksheet layout.

This make it hard to get the sum of Value for each Club. How do you get around this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you speak my mind, but I have no idea how to achieve that. Would you mind explain more about the array, dictionary or collection that you spoken of? @user1274820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The trick is to scan top-down, not left-to-right:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAllTotals2()
    Dim dict
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim c As Range, UL As Range
    Dim ID As String, nextID As String
    Dim lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, v As Long


    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Set UL = .Cells(1, 1)
        Set c = .Cells(1, 1)
        lastcol = UL.Column + .Columns.Count
        lastrow = UL.Row + .Rows.Count
    End With

    ID = ""
    While c.Column < lastcol
        Set c = Cells(UL.Row, c.Column + 1) ' top of column
        'check if column empty
        If c.End(xlDown).Row < lastrow Then
            ' scan "value" column for values; check for ID change!
            While c.Row <= lastrow
                If Left(c.Text, 5) = "value" Then
                    v = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    nextID = c.Offset(-2, -1)
                    ' may check nextID, needs to be "Club x"...
                    If nextID <> "" Then ID = nextID  ' ID changed
                    If dict.Exists(ID) Then
                        dict(ID) = dict(ID) + v
                    Else
                        dict.Add ID, v
                    End If
                    Set c = c.Offset(2, 0)  ' skip next 2
                End If
                Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)  ' row-wise
            Wend
        End If
    Wend

    ' show
    Dim key
    For Each key In dict
        Debug.Print key & " " & (dict(key))
    Next key
End Sub
```

Using `while` loops is not optimal in regard to performance. The code shown already skips empty columns as a start. I thank user1274820 for the `dictionary` code which fits perfectly for this task.

**edit:**
With working code I thought about optimizations. Scanning *all* used cells (plus backtracking) leads to the worst possible performance. The following code works by scanning columns top-down only if it contains the "value" keyword which is checked by simply counting it. Furthermore, the cell pointer is not incremented by one but jumps to the next non-empty cell.

```
Sub GetAllTotals3()
    Const keyword As String = "value:" ' got to be EXACT

    Dim dict
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim c As Range, UL As Range
    Dim ID As String, nextID As String
    Dim lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, v As Long

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Set UL = .Cells(1, 1)
        Set c = .Cells(1, 1)
        lastcol = UL.Column + .Columns.Count
        lastrow = UL.Row + .Rows.Count
    End With

    ID = ""
    While c.Column < lastcol
        ' check if column not empty
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c.EntireColumn, keyword) > 0 Then
            ' scan "value" column for keyword; check for ID change!
            While c.Row <= lastrow
                If c.Text = keyword Then
                    v = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    nextID = c.Offset(-2, -1)
                    ' may check nextID, needs to be "Club x"...
                    If nextID <> "" Then ID = nextID  ' ID changed
                    If dict.Exists(ID) Then
                        dict(ID) = dict(ID) + v
                    Else
                        dict.Add ID, v
                    End If
                End If
                  ' optim.: jump down to next filled cell
                Set c = c.End(xlDown)
            Wend
        End If
        ' go right to next column, start at top
        Set c = Cells(UL.Row, c.Column) ' top of column
        Set c = c.End(xlToRight)  ' optim.: jump right to next filled cell
    Wend

    ' show
    Dim key
    For Each key In dict
        Debug.Print key & ": " & (dict(key))
    Next key
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user1016274, I'll try it out when I have the free time.

Comment: I have tried out your code, @user1016274, I'm very impressed that the calculation time has been shortened, especially for a vast amount of data. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Based on @user1274820's answer, I made a little adjustment.

```
Sub GetAllTotals()
Dim dict
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim ra As Range
Dim rollback As Integer  'Additional variable

For Each ra In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If InStr(1, ra.Text, "Account Placement") > 0 Then

        rollback = -1
        'Rolling back number of rows to locate the Club ID
        Do Until ra.Offset(rollback,-1).Value <> ""
            rollback = rollback -1
        Loop

        With ra.Offset(rollback, -1)
            If dict.Exists(.Value) Then                
                dict(.Value) = dict(.Value) + ra.Offset(1, 1).Value
            Else                
                dict.Add .Value, ra.Offset(1, 1).Value
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next ra

Dim c
For Each c In dict
    Debug.Print c & " " & (dict(c))
Next c

End Sub
```

Like magic, everything fall perfectly into place.